# Replacing cross-database references after a schema compare in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

We often do a schema compare from our Dev environment into our TFS database project. Often these procedures have references to other databases (primarily the Stage DB). Every time we push our changes into TFS, we have to swap out the DB name with the SQLCmd variable.

Unfortunately, when there's 12 objects, we need to swap "DBStage" with [$(DBStage)] twelve times. It gets to be tedious. Is there an easier way?

TFS 2012

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+H - replace in all files. Search for DBStage., replace with [$(DBStage)].  Filter files to *.sql files only.